# how to point a domain name to free webhost server using dns

Tags: dns, nameservers

I am using free webhosting server. and i purchased a domain name. now how to point a domain name to free webhost?.

ex. my webserver address is abc.uco.im,

and my purchased domain name is xyz.com.

now how to point xyz.com to abc.uco.im using dns. please help, thank you.

Comment: This is not a programming question.  Try it on a network administration or webmaster forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go in your File Zone DNS and add a A host that point to the ip of your web server.

It will be like :

Host : @

Point : abc.uco.im

Answer (score 1):

The best place to resolve these questions is with your web host, and with the entity where you purchased the domain name. Specific instructions will vary according to those host services you choose.

Answer (score 0):

use webforwarding option in your purchased domain console . Go webforwading just enter your free host domain url there. Hence any one trying your new domain will automatically forwaded to your free domain address.